# How to remove non-essential files from Leopard

Tags: leopard, macos

I am cleaning up a really old mac to bring it back to use. It has an 80 gig hard drive and after wiping out downloads, documents, pictures, music, videos and unneccesary applications I am now stranded at about 48 gigs. I read that Leopard needs about 9 gigs, how do I get rid of the remaining 20 gb without reinstalling. Its been three and half years since I bought it and I could only find Part 2 of the recovery disk. (I have already gotten rid of iLife, iTunes, iWorks, Web Browsers, Printer Drivers etc as I need only terminal based facilities such as lynx and vi.) If anyone could point me to solutions for freeing up as much space as I can it'd be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Monolingual](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7758/monolingual) to trim the locales you don't require. This should trim at least a couple of GB.

The printer drivers are located in `/Library/Printers`. You can delete everything within the `Printers` directory (note, do not touch the `/System/Library/Printers/` directory).

Additionally, if it's a default install, it may have come with iLife. GarageBand loops also take up a few GB and are located in `/Library/Application Support/Garageband/Apple Loops/`.

There are other areas you can trim space, but those will net the biggest gains. You can also give programs like [DaisyDisk](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30689/daisydisk) a shot (or free equivalent). They'll show you how data is distributed on your hard drive, and allow you to further pinpoint cruft that can be removed.

Comment: thanks.. I got rid of the printer drivers.. I will try monolingual now.

Comment: @yayu No problem. I've edited my answer to include GarageBand loops, which take up a massive amount of space if you have iLife installed.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers .. I have freed up about 10 gb more. There's still some 10 gb lying somewhere... would trying to find it among the system files be worth the risk?

Comment: @yayu Give DaisyDisk (or equivalent) a try. Anything under /System is required. You can remove some things, but typically it won't affect hard disk space that dramatically. Most of the big ticket items are under /Library or your user (or /Applications).

Comment: @yayu also check out how to [remove built-in speech synthesis voices](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30697/how-can-i-delete-some-of-the-builtin-texttospeech-voices/31732#31732)!