# Location of downloaded voices - primarily used for announcement in Mac

Tags: mac, voiceover, voice

I need to delete the voices I downloaded for announcements/speech. It might be stored on some file system so anyoknow what's the location so I will go and delete the same. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Are you short of space? Have you de-selected them?

Comment: I am kind of person who don't want a single MB space wasted, and if you see its around 800 MB wasted..  by mistake I downloaded these however thanks to your suggestion, I de-selected and now its asking me to keep voice or delete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. To delete voices just uncheck them and press OK button.
2. In fact, location of voices is `/System/Library/Speech/Voices`

[How can I delete some of the built–in text–to–speech voices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30697/how-can-i-delete-some-of-the-built-in-text-to-speech-voices)